# Redirect non-IE users in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I wrote

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.*
RewriteRule .* /IE [R=403,L]
```

to redirect all ie users to the folder IE.

Then I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*MSIE.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} /IE
RewriteRule .* 404.html [R=404,L]
```

But it didn't work.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong var. `%{HTTP_HOST}` matches against the hostname, not the folder. I think you want something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*MSIE.*
RewriteRule ^/?IE /404.html [R=404,L]
```

Note that the `R=404` forces a 404 response, it doesn't actually redirect you anywhere.

Comment: @Mageek It means match either zero or one `/`. In .htaccess files, the leading slash is stripped off, so you don't need a `/` after the `^`, but in server and vhost configs, the leading slash is left there, so you need the `/` after the `^`. In your case, since it's in an htaccess file, you don't need the slash there at all

Answer (score 1):

The R flag only supports codes between 300 and 400, if you want to through a 403 Forbidden error, use the F flag, if you want to through a 404 Not found error, just redirect users to a non existent page.

**Edit :**

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE
RewriteRule ^IE unexistantpage.html [L]
```

Or if you want to make it forbidden then :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE
RewriteRule ^IE - [F,L]
```

Comment: I wrote `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*MSIE.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} /IE
RewriteRule .* unexistantpage.html [L]` and it didn't work...